# Call function initmap with parameters in gmaps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have this function, the default function from google maps api tutorial, I have just added 2 parameters latt and lngg.

```
function initMap(latt,lngg) {


    var uluru = {lat: latt , lng: lngg};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 15,
      center: uluru
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: uluru,
      map: map
    });
  }
```

And I want to call it like they call it :

```
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAmjE35Pm1eDdyF6Vg3WC69opkqLIVt3GY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

but using different parameters each time, because I will have 6000 maps, and I want to call the script for each function

I don't know if something like &callback=initMap(latt,lngg) is possible.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

You can't add parameters to a function that is used as a callback.  You can add variables in the global scope or in your HTML that can be used in the callback function.

For example:

```
<div id="mapcoords" data-lat="40" data-lng="-117" data-zoom="5"></div>

function initMap() {
  var uluru = {
    lat: parseFloat(document.getElementById('mapcoords').getAttribute("data-lat")), 
    lng: parseFloat(document.getElementById('mapcoords').getAttribute("data-lng"))
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: parseInt(document.getElementById('mapcoords').getAttribute("data-zoom")),
    center: uluru
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map
  });
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/bhmwnkzL/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var uluru = {
    lat: parseFloat(document.getElementById('mapcoords').getAttribute("data-lat")),
    lng: parseFloat(document.getElementById('mapcoords').getAttribute("data-lng"))
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: parseInt(document.getElementById('mapcoords').getAttribute("data-zoom")),
    center: uluru
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="mapcoords" data-lat="40" data-lng="-117" data-zoom="5"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
```

Comment: I want to include 100 maps for example in the same html page. I can get the latitude and longitude and make a loop for that, but I don"t know how

Comment: Use a class for the "map" div, process the array of elements returned by `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: Grateful for this solution, works 100%. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could have a separate script which sets the variables, and then have the initMap() call these variables.

```js
var latt;
var lngg;

function setCoords(latt,lngg){
  this.latt = latt;
  this.lngg = lngg;
}

function initMap() {

    var uluru = {lat: latt , lng: lngg};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 15,
      center: uluru
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: uluru,
      map: map
    });
  }
```

```html
<script type ='text/javascript'>setCoords(33.225488,-111.5955)</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAmjE35Pm1eDdyF6Vg3WC69opkqLIVt3GY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```