# How to display Google Maps with different location in multiple pages?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Is there possible to display a Google Map for each page with different locations ?

Comment: Yes.  Just initialize the map code on each page, and pass in different co-ordinates for the map center/marker as variables.  Make sure you have the same map container id on each page.

Comment: Related question: [Call function initmap with parameters in gmaps api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104164/call-function-initmap-with-parameters-in-gmaps-api) (store the coordinates for the location in the HTML, parse it out in the common javascript function)

Answer (score 0):

the solution is simple you just have to create a js script inside your page and create two variables:

archivo js.js

```js
function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: cordenax, lng: cordenay};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
}
```

archivo index.html

```html
 <body>
    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
    <div id="map"></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    var cordenax = -25.363;

    var cordenay = 131.044;
  </script>


   <script src="js.js"></script>


    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCd71PV2l5xNnRiVat4sKNV56CJcBhyS5E&callback=initMap">
    </script>

  </body>
```

the two variables indicate the coordinates, I hope you have understood

Comment: i use only 1 file .js for 1 site to include 1 function to init a map. Is there anyway to prevent from making a duplicate ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible.Try this code in differnt pages with differen id and differnt coordinates.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
       #map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```